# Android Studio debugging on Android 8.0 extremly slow compared to 4.0

Tags: android-studio

I switched from a china-phone (Swees x534, Android 4.4, API19) to a Nexus P6 to use it for debugging. I got that P6 today and updated it to Android 8.1, it still has to install some security updates.

On that china-phone everything debugged without any remarkable lags. In contrast to that, the Nexus needs even for showing the keyboard (when I select a textedit) 5-10 seconds. Loading another activity needs a lot more time or even crashes the whole app (which runs as expected on the china-phone). I did not change anything in my code.

The china phone did not have instant run, so I tried to disable it on the Nexus/Android Studio but it did not help anything.

I restarted Android Studio several times, tried "Debug App" and "Run App" but everytime it is the same behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The size of my retina-sized backgrounds caused the problem. As soon as I excluded them from my activity, everything was running nice and fast.

This video by Google Developers is exactly about these issues and introduces some helpful APIs: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HY9aaXHx8yA

I built a Helper class for all the image-stuff including this function:

```
public static Drawable resizeByFactor(String fileName, Integer factor, Resources resources, String packageName) {

    BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bitmapOptions.inSampleSize = factor;

    int imgRessourceBg = resources.getIdentifier(fileName, null, packageName);

    Bitmap BitmapResized = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, imgRessourceBg,bitmapOptions);

    return new BitmapDrawable(resources, BitmapResized);
}
```

so I can call it from anywhere in my project:

```
Drawable factorResizedImg = ImageHelper.resizeByFactor(imgName,2, getResources(),this.getPackageName());
backgroundImage.setImageDrawable(factorResizedImg);
```